# Accidentally walked into dog—how can I earn her trust again?

Tags: dogs

Recently, I accidentally walked into one of my dogs late at night in the dark. I didn't walk into her too hard and she didn't make any sound of pain, but she did get upset with me and went away. Though she's come up to me and has been happy with me petting her a few times, other times she gets nervous and scared when I walk by. I try to tell her that I'm being careful, but her attitude towards me hasn't changed.

I feel like an awful person for this happening in the first place and her being worried when I walk by her, especially as she's been attacked by other animals in the past. How can I earn her trust again and not scare her when I'm around? I've tried giving treats to her, and sitting down with some distance between us to try to reassure her, but she's still nervous around me. I just don't know what to do.

Comment: The linked 'duplicate' question has a not-great accepted answer, and I would like to provide an alternative - but it seems daft to be posting a new answer to a question that is three years old and where the original asker may not even own the same dog any more.  Furthermore, this question is about walking into a dog in the dark, and the other one is about kicking him while playing football: I am pretty clear that dogs would consider those two scenarios quite different.  I think this should be re-opened.